# After Deleting Files with SSH Acsess and Restart VPS Not Work and don't want to Start

Tags: ssh, vps

I have a VPS with Plesk Panel.
I wanted to delete some folders in file manager,but I have some problems with permissions, so I must delete them via SSH Accsess.

I went to the directory:

```
cd /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httdocs/myfolder/
```

Then I remove the folder with:

```
rm -rf /
```

After that, I tried to login into Plesk Panel,but i get **International SERVER ERROR.**
Also then i was tred to restart the VPS.I have restarted,and from that,my server is **Server stopped**

If i change the status,after some time again is stoped.I can't start basicly.

> My IP is: 62.75.141.188

It's bad, I can't connect now on server,becouse is stoped.I don't have access.

EDIT

I didn't make a backup.But i have it more files inside.Importnat for me.
How it's possible to get back?

Comment: A **strong** fail of the year candidate - you spoil us, bravo!

Comment: Please tell us this is an April Fool's joke? Right?

Answer (score 5):

You deleted the root directory, which is the base of your system. This destroys your system and removes all the files you need to run your server. You will need to reinstall and restore from backup.

Comment: So,all my files inside in server are now deleted? Right?
 Or just a root directory?
Tnx

Comment: ALL of them sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations! You successfully removed your server-root. You can start rebuilding your server from scratch or restore your backup.

Once you get your server back up and running, run this command to prevent you from doing it ever again

```
echo "alias rm=rm -i" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Your files are gone. You should contact support for the VPS hosting company you use and get them to help reinstall your VPS. There is a very slim chance they may have a backup of your files but it seems unlikely.

Now you've learned the hard way, you should investigate some backup solutions. The easiest is to just use an FTP client like filezilla to copy the files to your local system.